# Canvas position is hard to determine in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-canvas

I was playing with flutter custom painter and it's behavior seems to be pretty hard to understand. [image]

As you can see in the above image although I've specified to draw from the top of the screen it starts from above and displays a semi circle. What i want is to start the circle at the top of the screen  and it should remain same on all the devices. So what i want to achieve is something like this,

[image]

The circle should be positioned exactly on top of the screen.

What I've written so far,

```
class CustomCircle extends CustomPainter {

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red.withOpacity(0.4)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawPath(
      Path.combine(
        PathOperation.difference,
        Path()
          ..addRRect(RRect.fromLTRBR(
              0, 0, size.width, size.height, const Radius.circular(0))),
        Path()
          ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
              center: Offset(size.width * 0.5, 0), radius: size.width * 0.25))
          ..close(),
      ),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

= This is how I used it

```
  @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: CustomPaint(
            child: Container(),
            painter: CustomCircle(),
        )
```

Any suggestions to achieve the above UI will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you defined a center as `Offset(size.width * 0.5, 0)` so it's `y` value is zero, that's why it shows only a half of circle

Comment: @pskink Sorry didn't get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pskink mentioned, the center of the circle is not in the right place. You can do.

```dart
Path()
  ..addOval(
    Rect.fromCircle(
      center: Offset(size.width * 0.5, size.width * .25),
      radius: size.width * 0.25,
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore about [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) and [Rect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Rect-class.html)